# How do I change an image's position (x and y) dynamically at runtime in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, image, xamarin, xamarin.forms, position

I am using Xamarin.Forms and would like to change the position of an image dynamically (in code behind).

I have initially loaded the image statically by define it in an .xaml file. Then I would like to update the image's position (horizontally and vertically)  dynamically depending upon the a run time value from the user. The image should move as per a user input value.

Unfortunately I am not able to find a code sample for this.

How can I change the position of an image dynamically (in code behind)?

Answer (score 2):

You can manipulate the X and Y coordinates of an element using TranslationX and TranslationY properties.

To animate you can use the method TranslateTo:

```
public static System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool> TranslateTo (this Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement view, double x, double y, uint length = 250, Xamarin.Forms.Easing easing = null);
```

Where:

- **view** - The view to tanslate.
- **x** - The x component of the final translation vector.
- **y** - The y component of the final translation vector.
- **length** - The duration of the animation in milliseconds.
- **easing** - The easing of the animation.

Example how to animate the translation:

```
await image.TranslateTo (-100, 0, 1000);    // Move image left
await image.TranslateTo (-100, -100, 1000); // Move image up
await image.TranslateTo (100, 100, 2000);   // Move image diagonally down and right
await image.TranslateTo (0, 100, 1000);     // Move image left
await image.TranslateTo (0, 0, 1000);       // Move image up
```

Comment: `TranslateTo` works well. But when I try to move it for 2nd time. It returns to its original position and starts position from there

Comment: **solved for future reference** I saved the coordinates on a `TouchActionType.Released` and on the `TouchActionType.Moved` (on my case) I added on the xDif and yDif the saved value. The X or Y coordinates can be acquired with `'object'.TranslationX or .TranslationY`

Answer (score 0):

image.TranslationX = 20;
image.TranslationY = 20;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).